# Source map error when attempting to run grunt server

Tags: sass, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm unable to access my sass files when running grunt server. Not sure if this is just a file path/permission error or something greater.

Running `sudo grunt server` gives the same output

```
grunt server
Running "server" task

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task

Running "copy:video_fonts" (copy) task
Copied 4 files

Running "copy:video_js" (copy) task
Copied 1 files

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Error: Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for the source stylesheet.
         No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link to.
        on line  of standard input
    Use --trace for backtrace. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
%
```

I get the following error in my browser when I run grunt server --force

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for the source stylesheet.
  No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link to.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a grunt task that was perfectly working a couple of days ago. I suppose the problem was in some misalignment between the modules for that project (specifically grunt-contrib-sass) and the version of SASS installed.
I solved the problem by upgrading SASS, removing the node_modules folder inside my project and re-installing them.
I am sorry I cannot provide you any reason why it worked, but it did.

Update:

```
$ rm -R node_modules
$ npm install
```

Try:

```
$ grunt --debug --verbose sass
```

To get more info about what's happening while grunt runs.
S.